# Yii: APC Cache throwing error of Servers not being configured

Tags: yii, apc

I have configured APC Cache for YII application but when I put a variable in cache, I get the following error for line 222:

```
APC Cache Error
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu2tI.jpg

Following is my `config/main.php` entry for APC Cache:

```
        'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CApcCache',
            'servers'=>array(
                    array('host'=>'localhost','port'=>11211,'weight'=>60),
                    array('host'=>'localhost','port'=>11212,'weight'=>40),
                ),
    ),
```

Following is the code that I use to put data in cache:

```
    public function getReligion(){
    $lstofvals=Yii::app()->cache->get('RELIGION');
    if ($lstofvals===false){
        Yii::log('Loading Religion Data from List of Values.');
        $lstofvals=$this->PopulateLSTValsData('RELIGION');
        Yii::app()->cache->set('RELIGION', $lstofvals);
    }
    return $lstofvals;
}
```

I can see the output of apc.php in form of graphs and all other details.

Any help would much appreciated.

Please also confirm if my strategy to store the base data in cache is correct. I am new to Yii and found out about MemCache and APC Cache to be good candidates for such requirements.

Many thanks,
Faisal

Comment: the image did not get uploaded...here is the textual error output:         CException

Property "CApcCache.servers" is not defined.

D:\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(222)

$object=call_user_func_array(array($class,'newInstance'),$args);
216             }
217         }
218         else
219             $object=new $type;
220 
221         foreach($config as $key=>$value)
222             $object->$key=$value;
223 
224         return $object;
225     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the entire servers array from your config file. APC isnt distributed. Servers are used for memcache as far as I know